# server 2008 r2 rds farm with rds broker

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services, rds

OK, so the situation is like this:

- 4 RD Session hosts (farm name: sessions.domain.local)
- 2 RDS Brokers    (failover cluster - IP adress of the broker service
  is in the    domain/internal subnet)

Internally, it's working. I connect to the farm name and the broker either reconnects me to an existing session or makes a new connection on the RDSH.

Externally, i'm having problems. The current situation is this; i have port 3389 forwarded to a Windows NLB (which contains the 4 RDSH) ip adress on the domain subnet. When viewing event logs on the broker everything happens as it should: i get to the farm/RDSH/NLB then, one of the 4 RDSH directs my connection to the broker which then redirects me to a RDSH. The sad part is this: i cant login to the session/RDSH, over RDP nor remoteapp.
I've checked, rechecked and then double rechecked every possible configuration setting, browsed through, i think, pretty much every technet article there is about this topic. Lost my eyes on various sites describing this setup.

Questions:

- Is my port forward ok?
- Is the NLB with the 4 farm RDSH ok?
- Internal DNS name of the farm has the NLB ip adress, is that ok?

If anyone has any ideas what could be the problem or has a similar setup that is working and has the will to share :) i would be very very thankful.

Comment: The session Broker does load balancing, thats one of the main reasons to do it. So the windows LB is complicating matters

Comment: @Drifter104 WIndows LB is only here because i have to forward 3389 to a RDSH in the farm so that the "farm" asks the broker is there an existing session or to ask him where to direct the new session. I've tried many internal DNS setups. I've set farm dns name to NLB adress, not working. Tried putting all 4 RDSH in a RR DNS, not working also.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read that properly at all

Comment: I managed to solve this with 2 load balanced RDS gateways which "route" the connections to the farm/broker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question:

I managed to solve this with 2 load balanced RDS gateways which "route" the connections to the farm/broker.